# Reading contacts with loader manager

Tags: android

Im trying to make use of the LoaderManager and the CursorLoader to read the phone numbers of contacts. I'm able to read the contact's display name but Im not sure how to read the phone numbers. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

```
// These are the Contacts rows that we will retrieve.
static final String[] CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION = new String[] {
        Contacts._ID, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER };

// This is the Adapter being used to display the list's data.
SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;

// If non-null, this is the current filter the user has provided.
String mCurFilter;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // Give some text to display if there is no data. In a real
    // application this would come from a resource.
    setEmptyText("No phone numbers");

    // Create an empty adapter we will use to display the loaded data.
    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, null, new String[] {
                    Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER },
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 }, 0);

    setListAdapter(mAdapter);

    // Start out with a progress indicator.
    setListShown(false);

    // Prepare the loader. Either re-connect with an existing one,
    // or start a new one.
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    Log.i("FragmentComplexList", "Item clicked: " + id);
}

public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    // This is called when a new Loader needs to be created. This
    // sample only has one Loader, so we don't care about the ID.
    // First, pick the base URI to use depending on whether we are
    // currently filtering.
    Uri baseUri;
    if (mCurFilter != null) {
        baseUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
                Uri.encode(mCurFilter));
    } else {
        baseUri = Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    }

    // Now create and return a CursorLoader that will take care of
    // creating a Cursor for the data being displayed.
    String select = "((" + Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " NOTNULL) AND ("
            + Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1) AND ("
            + Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " != '' ))";
    return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), baseUri,
            CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION, select, null,
            Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
}

public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    // Swap the new cursor in. (The framework will take care of closing the
    // old cursor once we return.)
    mAdapter.swapCursor(data);

    // The list should now be shown.
    if (isResumed()) {
        setListShown(true);
    } else {
        setListShownNoAnimation(true);
    }
}

public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    // This is called when the last Cursor provided to onLoadFinished()
    // above is about to be closed. We need to make sure we are no
    // longer using it.
    mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.. this worked for me!

```
// This is the Adapter being used to display the list's data.
    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;

    // If non-null, this is the current filter the user has provided.
    String mCurFilter;

    @Override public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        // Give some text to display if there is no data.  In a real
        // application this would come from a resource.
        setEmptyText("No phone numbers");

        // We have a menu item to show in action bar.
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        // Create an empty adapter we will use to display the loaded data.
        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null,
                new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, },
                new int[] { android.R.id.text1}, 0);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);

        // Start out with a progress indicator.
        setListShown(false);

        // Prepare the loader.  Either re-connect with an existing one,
        // or start a new one.
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

    @Override public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // Place an action bar item for searching.
        MenuItem item = menu.add("Search");
        item.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search);
        item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
        View searchView = SearchViewCompat.newSearchView(getActivity());
        if (searchView != null) {
            SearchViewCompat.setOnQueryTextListener(searchView,
                    new OnQueryTextListenerCompat() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                    // Called when the action bar search text has changed.  Update
                    // the search filter, and restart the loader to do a new query
                    // with this filter.
                    mCurFilter = !TextUtils.isEmpty(newText) ? newText : null;
                    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, CursorLoaderListFragment.this);
                    return true;
                }
            });
            item.setActionView(searchView);
        }
    }

    @Override public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // Insert desired behavior here.
        Log.i("FragmentComplexList", "Item clicked: " + id);
    }

    // These are the Contacts rows that we will retrieve.
    static final String[] CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION = new String[] {
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
    };

    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        // This is called when a new Loader needs to be created.  This
        // sample only has one Loader, so we don't care about the ID.
        // First, pick the base URI to use depending on whether we are
        // currently filtering.
        Uri baseUri;
        if (mCurFilter != null) {
            baseUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(mCurFilter));
        } else {
            baseUri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
        }

        // Now create and return a CursorLoader that will take care of
        // creating a Cursor for the data being displayed.
        String select = "((" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " NOTNULL) AND ("
                + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " != '' )" + "AND ("+ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER +" != '0'"+"))";

        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), baseUri,
                CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION, null, null,
                null + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
    }

    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        // Swap the new cursor in.  (The framework will take care of closing the
        // old cursor once we return.)
        mAdapter.swapCursor(data);

        // The list should now be shown.
        if (isResumed()) {
            setListShown(true);
        } else {
            setListShownNoAnimation(true);
        }
    }

    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        // This is called when the last Cursor provided to onLoadFinished()
        // above is about to be closed.  We need to make sure we are no
        // longer using it.
        mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: The variable `String select` is not being used.